# Remove values in different intervals efficiently from a vector

Tags: r

I come across this question, it can be simply described as follow:

```
v <- 1:10
beg <- c(2, 8)
end <- c(5, 9)
```

I would like to remove [2-5] and [8-9] values, which should be:

```
d <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9)
```

My question is how to construct such vector `d` efficiently using `beg` and `end`?

Then,

```
final <- v[!(v %in% d)]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `seq` and `Map` combo.

```
unlist(Map(seq, beg, end))
# [1] 2 3 4 5 8 9
```

`Map` calls its first argument (`seq`) with pairwise values from the additional arguments, so the above is identical to:

```
unlist(lapply(seq_along(beg), function(i) seq(beg[i], end[i])))
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. It works well. First time to know `Map` function.